# Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am currently trying to pass a boolean value which was passed from an `onChange` function to a state variable.

```
let [toggleCheck, setToggleCheck] =useState(false);`

<input type="checkbox" id={"layout_toggle"} defaultChecked={toggleCheck} onChange={toggleOnchange}></input>`

const toggleOnchange = () => {
    setToggleCheck(!toggleCheck);
}
```

But it keeps throwing the below error.

`Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`

I tried using `document.getElementById()` to catch the element by id and use the value, but value changes getting delayed on the state variables when they set.
`setToggleCheck(element.checked)`

Comment: Is that a TypeScript error?

Comment: I do use typescript and i also used the  @ts-ignore. but it didn't help.

Comment: You should not use `defaultChecked` if you're controlling the checked state, instead use `checked`

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Here's a minimal reproducible example of your code, everything seems to work just fine. Also added a `console.log` on state change, so that you could see it actually does update as expected. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-1ojmrl?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: PS, note that we usually use `const` in `useState` declarations, not `let`. But that's unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. This has happened due to a wrong use of setState variable. I appreciate your help for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the type of "toggleCheck" to boolean to resolve the conflict like this:

`const [toggleCheck, setToggleCheck] = useState<boolean>(false)`